# how I can assign input to map function with set in the for loop

Tags: c++

I am wondering how I can use for loop and set for my input map!
here is what I think but there is some error!

actually I have a set Y and I want to map one element to 1 and other to zero! for example:

input: Y={2,3,4} 
output: [1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1] or in other words: {2->1, 3->0, 4->0},{2->0, 3->1,4->0},{2->0,3->0,4->1} 
I need my out put as a vector

```
for (iter = Y.begin(); iter != Y.end(); ++iter) {
  Map myMap;
  myMap.insert(std::make_pair(iter, 1));
  if (Y != iter) {
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(Y, 0));
  }
}
```

Comment: What type is `Y`? What type is `iter`? How does `if (Y != iter)` even compiling? Also lastly, to populate your map, you can use: `myMap[iter] = 1;`

Comment: hi Scohe001! Y is a set with some integer value! itter is in loop if you see the first line of my code you will see what is itter!

Comment: I wanna make one of the element of my set equal 1 and rest of elements equal 0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since you've declared your map, `myMap` inside the for loop, you're creating an entirely new map every iteration of the loop. You also won't be able to access it outside the loop. Therefore you should declare it before the loop.

From your comment, it looks like you're trying to map all items in your set to 0 except the first. In that case, begin by mapping them all to 0, and then just change the first after:

```
map<int, int> m;
for(auto iter = Y.begin(); iter != Y.end(); iter++) {
    m[*iter] = 0;
}
if(Y.size() != 0) {
    m[*Y.begin()] = 1;
}
```

**EDIT**

As per your comments below, this should be what you're looking for:

```
vector<map<int,int>> v;
for(auto iter = Y.begin(); iter != Y.end(); iter++) {
    map<int, int> m;
    for(auto iter2 = Y.begin(); iter2 != Y.end(); iter2++) {
        m[*iter2] = (*iter == *iter2);
    }
    v.push_back(m);
}
```

[See it in action here](https://ideone.com/V3X8mZ)

**EDIT 2**

After more comments, it sounds like this is what you're actually looking for:

```
int arr[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE] = {0}; //initialize whole array to 0's

int count = 0;
for(auto iter = Y.begin(); iter != Y.end(); iter++, count++) {
    arr[count][*iter-1] = 1; //pick out the specific values we want to be 1
}
```

(Note that I'm not sure what you mean by `e`, so I'm ignoring it)

[See it in action here](https://ideone.com/UVBEYR)

Comment: dear @Scohe001 I appreciate for your answer! thanks for your time! this is what I wanna do: I have a set with integer value! I want to make one of the elements equal 1 and other elements equal 0! and I want to repeat this for all elements of the set! I mean all element of the set should map to 1 for one time!how I can do that? I used map function and this is a part of my code! Y is a set! but there are some error

Comment: @sherek_66 I'm not sure what you mean...can you give me some example input and what the output should be?

Comment: sure! input: Y={2,3,4}      output: [1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1] or in other words: {2->1, 3->0, 4->0},{2->0, 3->1,4->0},{2->0,3->0,4->1}

Comment: @sherek_66 Ahh so you'd like the output to be a vector of maps? or a set of maps?? (also, these things--the more in depth description and example input/output--would be great to edit into your question. It would keep away the downvoters and maybe even get you some upvotes!)

Comment: thanks for your help! I will edit my post with a example! and I want my answer to be a vector with 0 and 1 element1

Comment: wooowwww! you wrote it very fast! I am really prod of you! smart brain! thank you very very much friend

Comment: I just get crazy error when I want to cout vectore!                                cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'

Comment: @sherek_66 see the link I gave you for one way to print it

Comment: thanks so much! I am new in this website! if there is any way that I can give u positive feedback let me know! you helped me a lot

Comment: just one more question is any way that I can use an array insist of vectore? becouse for example I have an array with size 5. and Y={1,5} so I need the first place of array to be 1 and 5th place 0, and again the first place to be 0 and 5th 1. I meant I need a output like this:[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1]

Comment: @sherek_66 if this is the answer you were looking for, you can give me a boost in reputation by [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @sherek_66 Ahh so you want the output to be an array of arrays of int?

Comment: sure i will! thanks again! yes I need an array! and actually the elements of the set are indices of that vector! for example input: Y={1,3,4} and B[6]={}

output: [1,e,0,0,e] , [0,e,1,0,e] , [0,e,0,1,e]

(e means it will be filled in the other parts of code}

Comment: I do appreciate!

Comment: I am phd student in mathematics! let me know if u needed any help in math